# How to apply CSS on parent element?

Tags: css

I am new in CSS, I need help in setting background colour of parent span based on which colour child span class has.

For example, I want to set blue background of `<span class="aciTreeItem">` if its first span child has class `background_blue`

MY HTML:

```
<span class="aciTreeItem">
  <span class="aciTreeIcon icon-server-not-connected background_blue"></span>
  <span class="aciTreeText">AWS(Cluster-1)</span>
</span>
```

My CSS:

```
span.aciTreeItem:has(.background_blue)
{
    background: blue;
}
```

But this is not working, Please suggest.

Comment: :has is not supported in CSS3 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has - and CSS as it is does not have a parent selector. You need to use script

Comment: There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.

Comment: You'll need a javascript solution. **.eg:** `var childWithClass = document.querySelectorAll('.aciTreeItem > .background_blue');

for (var i = 0; i < childWithClass.length; i++) {
  childWithClass[i].parentElement.style.background = "blue";
}`

Answer (score -2):

```css
span.aciTreeItem >.background_blue{
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="aciTreeItem">
  <span class="aciTreeIcon icon-server-not-connected background_blue">cvcv</span>
  <span class="aciTreeText">AWS(Cluster-1)</span>
</span>
```

Comment: You're selecting `.background_blue` and not `.aciTreeItem` like the op requested.